# How to get a table identity inserted by instead of insert trigger?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a problem described as follows: I have a table with one instead of insert trigger:

```
create table TMessage (ID int identity(1,1), dscp varchar(50))
GO
Alter trigger tr_tmessage on tmessage
instead of insert
as

--Set NoCount On

  insert into tmessage
  select dscp from inserted
GO
Alter proc P1
As

--Set NoCount On

insert into tmessage
(dscp)
values('some data')

Select SCOPE_IDENTITY()

GO
```

When I execute P1 it returns Null for SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of the identity of the table. I even tried Output clause in the insert statement in the proc. but again the output table Identity field that gets filled from inserted in the Output clause is 0 in this case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to **show us** the triggers!

Comment: Did you try @@IDENTITY instead of scope_identity()?

Comment: Try using `IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’)` instead of scope_identity(). [read this article to learn the differences.](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: @ZoharPeled
 I need the same Identity created in the session as there might be another sessions inserting into the table concurrently.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, I need the same Identity created in the session as there might be another sessions inserting into the table concurrently.Also there are another insertions in different tables during this as well. I just simplified the case here and put a very simple example. Is that a SQL bug??

Comment: @Sahand, no it is the bug in database design

Comment: from the article I've linked to, about scope_identity(): *"it will return the last identity value that you explicitly created, rather than any identity that was created by a trigger or a user defined function."* This explains why you can't get what you want using scope_identity in the stored procedure: the identity is created by the trigger and not by the procedure.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, just change the type of trigger to a regular one, after insert, and the it works.

Comment: Of course it will work. If you don't have an `instead of insert` trigger then the scope that the identity is inserted in is the stored procedure. Once you have an `instead of insert` trigger, then the stored procedure doesn't actually insert any data to the table itself. it only insert it to the `inserted` table of the trigger.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, I know what you mean, Maybe SCope_identity should return no value in this case, but how about using Output clause I mentioned above, It does not work either,Anyway, Can we do something about it while keeping the instead of insert trigger in place?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, yes, you are right. didn't notice that. thanks. so is there any way to get the identity in the proc without changing the trigger type. I think the answer is no. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've got yourself quite a pickle there.
From the one hand, you need the `instead of insert` trigger on your table, but from the other hand, you want to get the identity that this trigger generates back to the stored procedure that activated it.

Since there is no way to send parameters to and from triggers, you will have to do one of 3 things:

1. Find some way to eliminate the need for that instead of trigger.
   **This is my best recommendation.**
2. Break your stored procedure to 2 parts: One part will do everything until the `insert into` statement (including it), thus activating the `instead of insert` trigger, and the other part that will do all operations needed after the trigger. this way you can use the `scope_identity()` inside the `instead of insert` trigger and send it's return value to the second stored procedure as a parameter.
   **Note:** this design means you have to insert records one by one. should you try to insert more then one record, `scope_identity()` will only return the identity of the last row inserted by the trigger.
3. Find some way of passing data between the stored procedure and the instead of trigger. Since triggers can't except or return parameters, you will have to use either a temporary table or a regular table. This suggested solution is only suggested as a last resort, since it will complicate your code and probably cause some performance issues as well. Also, you will have to find a way to hold execution of the stored procedure until the instead of trigger will finish it's work. I can give you some pointers on how to share data between the procedure and the trigger, but I really suggest not to choose this solution.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  For solution  no 1. We have to  use the trigger because lots of business codes are in the another trigger for this table. We added this trigger to validate data before insertion. If we put the logic into the first trigger then on data being invalid event we had to rollback the trigger and it would cause the rollback of the entire process. But this way the second trigger only insert into the table if the data is valid otherwise nothing gets inserted and the process continues. For no 3 i have already fixed the problem using temp table in the proc and trigger.

Comment: But as you said i am not happy about it because of the potential performance issues. Can you please explain more about solution 2. In that case we still need to return the scope identity to the first proc and then pass it to the other one. How can it be done then?

Comment: The point of solution 2 is that you don't need to rerurn the identity to the first procedure, just use the second one to do whatever you did in the original one after the insert.

Comment: Btw, if this answer provided a solution to your problem you should accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved. If you found a different solution, post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Sorry i still don't understand solution 2.  I repeat my question.we run the scope_IDENTITY in the instead of insert.we cant even pass the id to the calling proc.how did you solve this problem? Am i missing something here?

Comment: You can't pass it back to the calling procedure but you can pass it to a different procedure that will do what you need after the trigger.

Comment: So you are saying moving the logic after the insert into a new proc and  calling it inside the trigger. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

SCOPE_IDENTITY() return the value from current scope and that is stored procedure outside from stored procedure it will be null.use @@identity to get last inserted identity.

Comment: Downvote reason: Please read the comments before suggesting an answer. Also, @@identity will return the last value of **any** identity in the hole database. not very useful for this situation.

Comment: right.no way to get identity column with instead type of trigger and scope identity.