# SQL Server - Instead of trigger (Issue with IDENT_CURRENT)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger on a table and I am seeing issues with using IDENT_CURRENT. Below is the sample code of my trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Some_Insert_Trigger] ON [dbo].[Table_A]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

//some code with temp table

  IF X==Y -- some logic
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table_B VALUES(....) -- Table B has a identity column
    SELECT @justinserted=IDENT_CURRENT('Table_B')  - now this @justinserted variable has the last inserted value
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
     --get the max of ID from Table B
  END     

// here insert happens into another table which relies on temp table and @justinserted

END
```

This works great sometimes, but not all the time. As per the documentation, IDENT_CURRENT is not limited by scope and session, so when two process hits the code at the same time there is high probability that IDENT_CURRENT returns identity value generated by a different process.
Here's a good article which gives a comprehensive explanation of what the issue I am facing.
http://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/ident-current

I cannot use OUTPUT here because the inserted contains the TableA and not TableB

Comment: Is there a reason `scope_identity()` is not working for you?

Comment: what actually you trying to achieve with this code? Which ID you want as return value

Comment: @ShannonSeverance: I tried using that but for whatever reason it returns NULL.

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName:  I am retrieving the Identity value of Table_B which is what I mentioned in my code. This trigger is on Table_A and has an insert statement to Table_B where I am trying to retrieve the Table_B identity value.

Comment: You need to troubleshoot the fact that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns NULL, not knee-jerk and use something far less reliable.

Comment: @AaronBertrand its for the same reason that is mentioned in the article I posted.

Comment: Oh, you mean the one I wrote? Why don't you do whatever you need to do with `@justinserted` in the instead of trigger on table_b then, instead of in the instead of trigger on table_a? Or change your logic so you can identify that row that was inserted in another way (surely the identity column isn't the only candidate key)? (Note: this is why we try to minimize the amount of work we do in triggers.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand :o lol btw a very good article. I have updated the code. I have certainly looked at the idea of moving that into instead of trigger on table_b along with the follow up logic but because of a lot of dependencies I am stepping back to do that.

Comment: Well I don't know of a better answer, sorry. You've wrapped yourself in 8 straight jackets and want a single strap to undo them all.

Comment: Mr. Bertrand  is one of the real SQL Server gurus and I always take his advice. We are fortunate that he shares his very extensive knowledge with us and I would save a lot of time and listen to him.

Comment: Any time I see TSQL code that gets the maximum value of an identity column I ponder what will happen when the last row added gets deleted and the maximum value retreats a little. Often a sign of a lurking time bomb.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've read your article and understood the problem. now, almost 2 years after written, do you have any suggested solution to this kind or problems? I'm asking because I've tried to [answer someone here that had the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232125/how-to-get-a-table-identity-inserted-by-instead-of-insert-trigger/30235680#30235680) as Kendal a while back, but couldn't come up with any real solution either. btw, lmao on "Oh, you mean the one I wrote?"....

Comment: @Zohar some combinations just don't work well together, like encryption & compression. Multiple triggers and identity columns is another one. One idea - if you can't move the logic elsewhere and you really don't have another way to uniquely identify the row(s) you inserted - would be to add a nullable uniqueidentifier column to the table, put newid() into a variable (or a table variable if you're inserting multiple rows), insert that with the data, then update it to null after you've retrieved the rows. The schema changes but no real impact on table size. Filtered index where not null = good.