# Get identity after Instead of insert trigger

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, triggers

I am using Hibernate with MSSQL server writing the software that integrates with an existing database. There is an `instead of insert` trigger on the table that I need to insert into and it messes up `@@Identity`, which means on Hibernate's `save` I can't get the id of inserted row. I can't control the trigger (can't modify it). I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232125/how-to-get-a-table-identity-inserted-by-instead-of-insert-trigger) question, but it involves procedures, which my trigger does not have, so I thought my question is different enough. I can't post the whole trigger, but hopefully I can post enough to get the point across:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TrigName ON TableName
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION
-- several DECLARE, SET statements
-- a couple of inserts into other tables for business logic
-- plain T-SQL statements without procedures or functions
...

-- this is the actual insert that i need to perform
-- to be honest, I don't quite understand how INSERTED table 
-- was filled with all necessary columns by this point, but for now
-- I accept it as is (I am no SQL pro...)
INSERT INTO ClientTable (<columns>)
SELECT <same columns> from INSERTED

-- a couple of UPDATE queries to unrelated tables
...

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

I was wondering if there is a reliable way to get the id of the row being inserted? One solution I thought of and tried to make is to install an `on insert` trigger on the same table that writes the newly inserted row into a new table I added to the db. I'd use that table as a queue. After transaction commit in Hibernate I could go into that table and run a `select` with the info I just inserted (I still have access to it from the same method scope), and I can get the id and finally remove that row. This is a bulky solution, but best I can come up with so far.

Would really appreciate some help. I can't modify existing triggers and procedures, but I can add something to the db if it absolutely does not affect existing logic (like that new table and a `on insert` trigger).

To sum up: I need to find a way to get the ID of the row I just inserted with Hibernate's `save` call. Because of that `instead of insert` trigger, hibernate always returns identity=0. I need to find a way to get that ID because I need to do the insert in a few other tables during one transaction.

Comment: It is not totally clear to me what you are trying to do but to get the value of the identity column in an insert you should the OUTPUT clause. It can return all the values inserted at once (remember that triggers fire once per operation, not once per row). You can use the output values to insert into the other table along with the newly created identity values.

Comment: Hi @SeanLange I will update the qn, but I need to find a way to get the ID of the row I just inserted with Hibernate's `save` call. Because of that `instead of insert` trigger, hibernate always returns 0. I need to find a way to get that ID because I need to do the insert in a few other tables during one transaction.

Comment: @SeanLange where would I put that OUTPUT clause? I can't modify that `instead of insert` trigger.

Comment: Is the insert done in a procedure? I have the feeling that it isn't. Can you modify the code that does the actual insert? That would be where you want to capture the identity values using output.

Comment: @SeanLange The insert is done in the trigger I have in my post above. I can't post the entire trigger, but as far as I can see there are no procedures in the trigger.

Comment: But what does the original insert? It has to come from somewhere. That may be the code you can modify. If you can't touch this instead of trigger there is little point in even looking at it.

Comment: Unless you jave some natural key that you can identify records before they are inserted, You can only get the identity value back inside the trigger, so if you can't modify the trigger that's a problem

Comment: @ZoharPeled,@SeanLange I posted a possible solution that worked so far. Maybe it will provide more details and context about the question. I'd really appreciate some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found *an* answer for my question. To reply to @SeanLange's comment: I can't actually edit insert code - it's done by another application and inquiry to change that will take too long (or won't happen - it's a legacy application). What I did is insert another trigger `on insert` on the same table. Since I know the order of operations in the existing `instead of insert` trigger I can see that the last `insert` operation will be in the table I want so that means my `on insert` trigger will fire right after that. In the scope of that trigger I have access to `inserted` table out of which I pull out the id.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Client_OnInsert ON myClientTable
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ID int;
  SET @ID = (select ClientID from inserted);
  INSERT INTO ModClient (modClientId)
  OUTPUT @ID
  VALUES (@ID);
END
GO
```

Then in Hibernate (since I can't use `save()` anymore), I use a NativeQuery to do this insert. I set parameters and run the `list()` method of NativeQuery, which returns a `List` where the first and only argument is the id I want.

This is a bulky way, I know. If there is anything that's really bad that will stand out to people - please let me know. I would really appreciate some feedback on this. However, I wanted to post this answer as a potential answer that worked so far, but it does not mean it's very good. For this solution to work I did have to create another small table ModClient, which I will have to use as a temp id storage for this exact purpose.